# Override css of content by using a parent div

Tags: html, css

I have an element that I use on a page, than I use it on another page and wanted to assign override some of the CSS value so I'm assigning a parent div but it doesn't seem to be working.

The default css is

```
.mana-curve{
 width: 250px;
}
```

Now on another another page I'm trying to override the mana curve setting by using a parent div that is only on the new page

```
#deck-list .mana-curve{
 width: 450px;
}
```

Although when the .mana-curve div is inside the deck-list div it doesn't override to the new width.

Comment: Did you check what's happening using your browser's developer tools?

Comment: Yes, it just ignores the #deck-list completely and shows .mana-curve

Comment: It works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KuBz5/) as you want even if i put `.mana-curve` after `#deck-list .mana-curve` so there must be something else youre not telling us

Comment: That is what is weird, i have used this method all the time but can't figure it out with this http://hearthstoneplayers.com/deck/strifecros-shaman/ is the page. The issue is with the black graph box.

Comment: Dude. The `id` of div which the `.mana-curve` inside is `deck-list-manacurve` in your page

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have one element with class `mana-curve`, and another one with id `deck-list`. But neither of them is a descendant of the other one.

Instead, `.mana-curve` is a child of `'#deck-list-manacurve'`, so you should use

```css
#deck-list-manacurve > .mana-curve
```